# How chrome browser priorities script files?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting medium priority for my javascript URL. I refer some other sites it show high priority for javascript URL.  Reference chrome devtool images below. What basis chrome browser priorities script files? is It affect my performance?

[image: Priority - Medium]

[image: Priority - High]

Comment: See [Resource Fetch Prioritization and Scheduling](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bCDuq9H1ih9iNjgzyAL0gpwNFiEP4TZS-YLRp_RuMlc) and [script preloading](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/link-rel-preload)